# Function keys In UFT

Tags: automation, ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft

1. Version : Using HP-UFT Tool 11.53 Build 0382.
2. Question :Wanted to automate Function key F9 for my script but I am not able to as I do for normal keyboard keys what is method to do so.
3. Work Done : Try to Record for function key Hitting But no record is create for it.
4. Scenario : In my application on F9 press one popup would come and I just want to test it using UFT Tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sendkeys`, if you want to hit any key from keyboard. Try the below code.

```
Set oWscript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWscript.sendkeys"{F9}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In UFT `Window` has a `Type` method, the parameter for this method is a string but there are special values for special keys. For you case you probably want `micF9`.

Please look and `Window.Type`'s documentation for more details.

Comment: Please let me know where I get such document and other stuff.
If any Link for some other keys and keywords. And thanks for answer.

Comment: @rhatwar007 it's in UFT's documentation, just press `F1` in UFT.